# When you have multiple splits, how to close a particular one only, keeping nerdtree open?

Tags: vim

I have NerdTree installed in vim. Upon startup, I press a keybind and it brings up NerdTree. This takes up the entire window, I then go to a file that I want and type "o". This would open the file in a horizontal split. So, I have NerdTree on the left, and the file on the right.

Say I have more files opened, if I close one file by pressing ":q" or even "C+w+c", vim would automatically close the one file and have NerdTree maximized again. This is fine for 1 file, but if you have more than 1 files opened, it is annoyed to repopulate the windows layout.

What I want is if I close the file, is it possible to retain the layout? In other words, if I close one file, the file below it would take its place and NerdTree is still split on the left?

TLDR: How to make NerdTree's layout stick after closing a split?

EDIT: Please refer to the screenshots below:

[image: Open vim then open NerdTree]

[image: Open file1 by "o" while in NerdTree]

[image: Open file2 by "o" while in NerdTree]

At this point, the buffers contain file1, file2 and NerdTree.
If I close file1, I should expect file1 closes but the layout still have NerdTree on left and file2 on the right.  In other words, picture 3. But, using ":wq" on file1 gets this:

[image: Closing file1 will close the layout]

Comment: Please add screenshots of expected and actual behavior.

Comment: @svlasov I just added the images to explain.

Answer (score 0):

`:wq` does not close the file. What it does actually is writing file to disk and **closing the window** (if you have only one window, that also exits Vim).

It is unnecessary to close files in Vim. However you can still do it:

1. If you don't want the file to be listed in `:ls`, you can delete its buffer from the list (the file will still remain in memory):

```
:bdelete
```

2. You want to free memory taken by the file, unload the buffer (the buffer will remain in the list):

```
:bunload
```

3. If you want to remove any traces about the file from current Vim instance, it is like `bdelete` and `bunload` combined and more:

```
:bwipeout
```

Read the help page about each command for better understanding.